# JMeter Groovy unable to resolve class

Tags: mongodb, groovy, jmeter

I want to use JMeter (5.6.2) to measure the performance of a MongoDB database.

From https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/mongodb-performance I got a 'Helo world' code. Added with that the credentials from https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.5/driver/tutorials/authentication/. Led up to the code:

```
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClients;
import com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings;
import com.mongodb.ServerAddress;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;
import com.mongodb.MongoCredential;

import org.bson.Document;

import java.util.Arrays;

try{
    MongoCredential credential = MongoCredential.createCredential(vars.get("user"), vars.get("databaseName"), vars.get("password"))
    MongoClientSettings settings = MongoClientSettings.builder()
      .applyToClusterSettings {builder ->
          builder.host(Arrays.asList(new ServerAddress(vars.get("mongoHost"),vars.get("mongoPort").toInteger())))}
      .credentials(credential)
       .build();

       MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create(settings);

       MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase(vars.get("databaseName"));
       MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection(vars.get("collectionName"));

       vars.putObject("Collection", collection);

       return "Connected to " + vars.get("collectionName");
}
catch (Exception e) {
    SampleResult.setSuccssful(false);
    SampleResult.setResponseCode("500");
    SampleResult.setResponseMessage("Exception: " + e);
}
```

Changing the path `import com.mongodb.client.MongoClient;`
does not solve the issue. Also using Java instead of Groovy does not solve it.

When I run this I got the error:

```
Response message:javax.script.ScriptException: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script2.groovy: 1: unable to resolve class com.mongodb.client.MongoClient
    @ line 1, column 1.
    import com.mongodb.client.MongoClient;
```

What is it that I'm missing?

Note: I'm using /lib/mongodb-driver-3.4.2.jar and Groovy 3.0.17

**Edit**: placing the driver in /lib/ext does not solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The [article you've mentioned](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/mongodb-performance) says:

> In order to use MongoDB Java Driver in your JMeter scripts, download the latest version of the mongo-java-driver jar file and put it to lib/ext folder under your JMeter home folder.

So if you already dropped the [MongoDB Java Driver](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/java-drivers/) of your choice to [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) ("lib" folder of your JMeter installation) you will need to restart JMeter to pick up the .jar.

If you haven't choose the version which is used by the system you're trying to simulate. The code should also be taken from there as you don't need to run a "hello world", you need to mimic real-life usage of your MongoDB instance.

Comment: Thank you @Dmitri T.  It doesn't make a difference if I place the mongodb-driver-3.4.2.jar in the /lib or in the /lib/ext directory. It remains saying that "unable to resolve class com.mongodb.client.MongoClient"

Comment: I think it's `com.mongodb.MongoClient` for version 3.4.2: https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver/3.4.2/com/mongodb/MongoClient.html

Comment: Solved using MongoDB driver 3.12.14